# overlay position on div-hover

Tags: html, css

I have a 2-by-2 grid of images arranged using `float` property in CSS. 
I want to show a small overlay on each image when i hover over it, by switching its opacity from 0 to 1 on hover. My code works great when i hover the images in the top row. 
But when I hover over the lower-row images, the overlay activated is still the one from the top row.

I think its an issue with positioning.

My code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/zZXZX/27/

PS : please dont mind the minor faults with the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are positioning your overlay in absolute, without specifying a relative parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/zZXZX/28/

`position:absolute` positions your overlay with offsets relative to its first parent that is not `position:static`, or if none are found, the document root.

Answer (score 2):

```
.movie{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
```

You need to add `position:relative` to your .movie class. `position:absolute` looks for its closest parent item that is not static position.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative` to `.movie`.